# Is there a legal way to obtain hold guard armour?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Okay, I admit, I'm  a huge fan of the Hold Guard Armour, especially the colour schemes, OMG awesome, but I was wondering, is there a way to obtain it without looting it from a corpse or stealing it?

I'd just like to mention as well, I included both killing and coming across dead guards as looting from the corpse.

Comment: Take an arrow to the knee and quit adventuring?

Comment: The only way to get this armour is to either join the storm cloaks (which is the same). I'm not too sure about the helmet though.

Comment: The big limitation here is that you are not willing to loot dead guards. That first quest at the tower near Whiterun has a bunch of dead guards whose armor you can loot. And I have gotten armor for other holds when guards died fighting a dragon.  In my Hearthfire house I have statues of each of the guards from the nine holds collected without ever personally killing a guard.

Answer (score 5):

No. The only way to get most of the hold guards armors is by killing them, or stealing from them with the [**Perfect Touch**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pickpocket) perk.
Or you could just get an npc to come and murder them for you :P

There are a few armors you can get other ways.

**List of hold specific armor**

For completion sake this list contains not only the armors but also the shields and helmets.

Also, Adrianne Avenicci in Whiterun and Lucan Valerius in Riverwood sell only the Whiterun Guard's Armor.

Stormcloak armour is different though as they don't wear 'Stormcloak boots' they wear fur ones.

The stormcloak armour ID's are below:

Hide Helmet - 00013913
Scaled Helmet - 0001B3A1
Stormcloak Helmet - 000A6D79
Stormcloak Cuirass - 000A6D7B
Fur Gauntlets - 000A6D7D
Fur Boots - 000A6D7F

[**Hold armor list**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Specialty_Gear#Guard_Equipment)

And the Eastmarch Guard Helmet cannot be acquired at all without console spawning.
The Eastmarch helmets ID: 0010559d

**Console spawning**

If on a PC, you could spawn in the armour or maybe there is a mod to allow you to do so.

To find ID's to spawn in armour on a PC, click here. [**Hold Guard Armor**](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Hold_Guard_Armor) from [**Elder Scrolls Wikia.**](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_Wiki)
Then click your wanted armour set, look for the armour and under the picture is an ID.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the edits but Adrianne and Lucan don't actually sell the Whiterun armours. As on the 'Hold armor list' it states for all armours that they are only found on guards.

Comment: Im sorry, my bad, I just found out that they ARE sold. Added some things and edited it back in.

Comment: Looting a guard someone else kills is legal. That's a legal way to get the armor.

Comment: @DCShannon According to the OP looting a corpse counts as stealing for his purposes.

Comment: @JMac Yeah I guess they did say that. I was just thinking of looting a murdered corpse as being stealing. Odd stance regarding found corpses.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a set of Whiterun Guard armor legally (sans the shield), in the inventory of the very first dragon you fight, the one that Jarl Balgruff send you, Irileth, and some guards to go kill. You'll notice that the guards at the tower that was attacked say that a few of their friends tried to run for it and were eaten by the dragon. The basis is that the armor belonged to one of them, since it is in the inventory of that dragon.

There is a Whiterun shield in Jarl Balgruff's room that you can easily steal.

Tip: if you want to remove its "stolen" status:

> put it in a chest and tell your follower to take all from that chest. I'd recommend an empty or nearly empty chest for this. Once you take it from them, it will no longer be counted as "stolen".

A set of Markarth Guard's armor can be obtained while doing a quest for the Thieves Guild, where you must get a charcoal rubbing of some falmer runes. You can get it either by killing one of the few guards present in that area (it will not count as illegal, so no bounty on you), or by looting it from some who are already dead, in an area with poison gas of some sort (you will continuously take damage while there, so you'll know it when you see it).

If you side with the Imperials and take over Riften, then some former Riften Guards (still wearing their armor) will occasionally attack the imperial troops stationed there as guards, similar to how unnamed thieves will aggro the Riften Guards. You can loot the armor from them once they're killed by the imperial soldiers.

For Solitude Guard armor, there are a few lone guards outside of the gates that can be stealth killed for no bounty (nobody sees it, it didn't happen :D). You can get a specially enchanted Solitude Guard's shield as a quest reward for that quest that involves stopping Potema from returning from the dead.

Comment: +1 for the content, but this seriously needs some white space. Paragraphs are your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the armor and helm from the first dragon you kill, story wise, while the shield can be pick-pocketed from a guard or looted from a dead guard who feel during a fight, like when they fight vampires, a dragon or Stormcloaks (they, sometimes, attack the WR guards in Rorikstead). I kinda wish you got a WR shield from a quest like that one you get for a quest in Solitude.

Answer (score -3):

For PC

- Approach the guard
- Open console command
- Click on the guard, and you'll see the guard's ID
- type kill and the guard will be dead
- loot the guard's armor and his shield

This is the easiest way I think to obtain all guard's armor. No bounty and no need to battle againts him.

Comment: *"is there a way to obtain it **without looting it from a corpse** or stealing it? I'd just like to mention as well, **I included both killing** and coming across dead guards **as looting from the corpse**."* - the question asks about doing it without killing

Comment: Not to mention, if you are going to use console commands, `additem` seems a lot more simple to me ([see Sk4llsRPG's answer above](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/178612/42464).