# How can I get Whiterun Guard Armor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I get the sick looking Whiterun guard armor? P.S. I already have the shield and armor, how do I get the helmet to top it off?

Comment: Near duplicate: [Is there a legal way to obtain hold guard armour?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/178099/108003)

Answer (score 4):

You can find Whiterun guard's clothes in

- Dead Guards
- Guard's Barracks
- Stealing from guards (Stealing Equipped items perk)
- The guards that help fight the dragon at the watchtower (Main Quest)

After that it varies, I believe all guards drop the armor, however some guards don't drop the helmet for some reason (even if they have it)

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto oak's post you can also get it from chests, dragons will sometime have armour on them after killed, and killing white run guard she in general.

Answer (score 0):

The first dragon you fight at the white run tower has the armor and helmet